# Basis (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's have vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in \mathbb R^4$. Prove that these vectors form basis (1), determine if they are orthogonal and/or orthonormal (2). Then make a transition matrix $T_{\epsilon\alpha}$  from basis $\alpha$ to standard basis and use it to get coordinates of vector $w=(2,3,5,1)_\alpha$ in standard basis (3).
$$v_1=(1,1-1,1),v_2=(1,-1-1,-1),v_3=(0,1,0,-1),v_4=(1,0,1,0) $$
(1) Prove that these vectors form a basis.

> I did following:
>   $$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 1 & -1 &1 \\
> 1 & -1 & -1 &-1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 &-1 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  
> \end{array} \right)=A$$
>   $$\left| \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 1 & -1 &1 \\
> 1 & -1 & -1 &-1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 &-1 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  
> \end{array} \right|=-8 \ $$
>   $|A| \neq 0 \implies$ Vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ are linearly independent and form basis.

(2) Determine if they are orthogonal and/or orthonormal.

> I did following:
>   $$v_1\cdot v_2=(1-1+1-1)=0$$
>   $$v_1\cdot v_3=(0+1+0-1)=0$$
>   $$v_1\cdot v_4=(1+0-1+0)=0$$
>   $$v_2\cdot v_3=(0-1+0+1)=0$$
>   $$v_3\cdot v_4=(0+0+0+0)=0$$
>   $\implies$ Basis is orthogonal.
>   $$|v_1|=\sqrt {1+1+1+1}=\sqrt4=2$$
>   $$|v_2|=\sqrt {1+1+1+1}=\sqrt4=2$$
>   $$|v_3|=\sqrt {0+1+0+1}=\sqrt2$$
>   $$|v_4|=\sqrt {1+0+1+0}=\sqrt2$$
>   $\implies$ Basis is not orthonormal.

(3) Make a transition matrix $T_{\epsilon\alpha}$  from basis $\alpha$ to standard basis and use it to get coordinates of vector $w=(2,3,5,1)_\alpha$ in standard basis.

> $$T_{\epsilon\alpha}=A^{-1}=\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
> \frac14 & \frac14 & 0 & \frac12 \\
> \frac14 & -\frac14 & \frac12 &0 \\
> -\frac14 & -\frac14 & 0 & \frac12 \\
> \frac14 & -\frac14 & -\frac12 & 0  
> \end{array} \right)$$
>
> $$u=A^{-1} w$$ Where $u$ is in standard basis?

Is (1) and (2) correct and can you help me out with (3) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that a vector $w$ written in terms of basis $\alpha = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ has the form:

$$( a, b, c, d)_{\alpha} = 
av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 + dv_4$$

It's also important to remember that when your vectors $v_i$ are written in terms of coordinates, that these are coordinates with respect to the *standard* basis.  For example,

$$( 1,  0,  0, 0)_{\alpha} = 
v_1 = 
(1,  1, -1, 1)_{\epsilon}$$

Therefore, the matrix $T_{\epsilon \alpha}$ should have the property that:

$$T_{\epsilon \alpha} (a,b,c,d) = a( 1, 1, -1, 1)+
b( 1,  -1, -1,-1) + c( 0,  1, 0,  -1)+
d( 1,  0,  1, 0)$$

Thus, $T_{\epsilon \alpha} = A$, the matrix you've written above, whose rows are the standard-basis representations of the vectors $v_i$ in the given order.

Comment: So $T_{\alpha\epsilon}=A^{-1}$ and $u=w\cdot T_{\alpha\epsilon}$  where $u$ is $w$ in standard basis?

Comment: @MartinB, $u = w\cdot T_{\alpha \epsilon}$ would express a vector $w$ which is *given* in standard $\epsilon$ basis as a vector $u$ in basis $\alpha$.

Comment: @MartinB:  Also, your (1) and (2) calculations are fine... except you forgot to check that $v_2 \cdot v_4 = 0$.

Comment: So $u = w\cdot T_{\epsilon\alpha}$, where $u$ is in standard basis. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @ShaunAult Is the vector $u =(1,-7,2,7)$ ? MartinB is sitting next to me :)

Comment: I got $T_{\epsilon \alpha}(w) = wA = (6, 4, -4, -6)$.

Comment: Your (3) is still incorrect.  We have $T_{\epsilon \alpha} = A$, not $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the matrix that transforms the standard basis to $\alpha$.  Then the columns of $A$ are your vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.  Also, for each standard basis element $e_i$, we have $Ae_i=v_i$.  Thus $e_i=A^{-1}v_i$.  Therefore you need to calculate $A^{-1}$.

Comment: I've edited my question, is it correct now? And what about (1) and (2)?